# Jar file containing the class - com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory

Tags: jms

What is the jar file containing the class: `com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory`

I am getting the following error: `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory` while trying to run a JMS based application in Sun Java System App Server.

Regards
Chaitanya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jar finder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory) suggest that it is
appserv-rt.jar